# Flutter: Undefined name 'SystemMouseCursors'

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a problem with the MouseRegion Widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MouseCursor-class.html). When i will change the cursor with SystemMouseCursors it give me the error undefined name 'SystemMouseCursors'.
Must i import a package or something else? I don't find a solution on Stack Overflow or other sites.

```
Container loginText() {
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
  child: MouseRegion(
    cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _toLogin(),
      child: Text(
        'Bereits registriert? Zum Login',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have no solution found until now, but when I find a solution i post it hear.

Answer (score 0):

For SystemMouseCursors to work, you need to import the flutter rendering package.

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
```

I ran into this same issue myself when using SystemMouseCursors for the first time and found your question while searching for the answer. Here is a full working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Text(
          'CREATE AN ACCOUNT',
          style: TextStyles.textWhiteBold,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        onTap: () =>
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Signup(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

}
```